# PHP Fatal error Class Not Found - Composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm setting up a project with Composer and am getting this error in the PHP Error log when I try to run it:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class
>   'SocialConnect\Common\Http\Client\Curl' not found in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/login-platform/index.php:3

Here is the directory structure:

```
.
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── index.php
├── vendor
│   └── ...
```

The index file just has this so far:

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

?>
```

Here's composer.json:

```
{
  "require": {
    "socialconnect/auth": "^1.2"
  }
}
```

Here's /vendor/socialconnect/common/composer.json:

```
{
"name": "socialconnect/common",
"description": "Common component",
"license": "MIT",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Dmitry Patsura",
        "email": "talk@dmtry.me"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5",
    "ext-json": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^2.8",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.2",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^5.3|^6.0",
    "doctrine/cache": "^1.5.1"
},
"suggest": {
    "ext-curl" : "Allows to use Http\\Client\\Curl",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle" : "Allows to use Http\\Client\\Guzzle, require guzzlehttp/guzzle:~5.3|~6.0."
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "SocialConnect\\Common\\": "src/"
    }
}
}
```

I'm new to composer. The `socialconnect` folder is within the vendor directory. How do I connect it?

Thanks!

Edit: The error received after Hassan's answer:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - The requested package socialconnect/common ^1.1 exists as socialconnect/common[0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.3, 0.2.4, 0.2.5, 0.2.6, 0.2.7, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6.0, 0.7, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, dev-master] but these are rejected by your constraint.
>     Problem 2
>       - socialconnect/auth 1.2.2 requires socialconnect/common ^1.0 -> satisfiable by socialconnect/common[1.0.0, 1.0.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - socialconnect/auth 1.2.1 requires socialconnect/common ^1.0 -> satisfiable by socialconnect/common[1.0.0, 1.0.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - socialconnect/auth 1.2.0 requires socialconnect/common ^1.0 -> satisfiable by socialconnect/common[1.0.0, 1.0.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - socialconnect/auth 1.2.2 requires socialconnect/common ^1.0 -> satisfiable by socialconnect/common[1.0.0, 1.0.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>       - Installation request for socialconnect/auth ^1.2 -> satisfiable by socialconnect/auth[1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2].

Comment: In the vendor map of SocialConnect is another composer.json. Inside of that file there is a part that defines the namespace of the package. Could you post that?

Comment: You should put your project files in their own subdirectory, and then set your web server's document root to that subdir. Otherwise, your web server will happily serve any file in the project, including those that aren't meant to be consumed by browsers. E.g., with your current layout, you can request `http://yourdomain.com/composer.json`.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan OK I included SocialConnect's composer.json in the original post.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Good point yea usually all libraries and config files are outside of my public_html folder. I'm just developing something quickly on local at the moment.

Comment: Your question's parts do not really fit together. Your `index.php` only runs the Composer autoloader, however you report that this already triggers a fatal error. I cannot see anything that should do this in the single package you installed. Also you require `socialconnect/auth`, but present the `composer.json` of `socialconnect/common`. And the last thing in your edit: You present an error message that complains about not being able to install `socialconnect/common` in version 1.1, which is not surprising because the latest version is 1.*0*.1. Would you be able to overhaul your question?